# Is $\phi B(\omega,\;\cdot\;)$ Lebesgue integrable over $[0,\infty)$ for a real-valued Brownian motion $B$ and $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Is $$W(\phi):=\int_{[0,\infty)}\phi(t)B_t\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$$ well-defined?

Let $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $K:=\operatorname{supp}\phi\cap [0,\infty)$. I would argue that $$\left\|\phi1_{[0,\infty)}B(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{L^1(\lambda)}\le\underbrace{\left\|\phi\right\|_{L^\infty(\lambda)}}_{<\infty}\underbrace{\left\|1_KB(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{L^1(\lambda)}}_{=:M(\omega)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega$$ and that $M<\infty$ almost surely, since $K$ is compact and $B$ is almost surely continuous.

How do I deal with the null set on which $B$ is not continuous? Please note that $W$ is the distributional stochastic process associated with $B$. Maybe we don't care about its values on a null set.

Answer (score 0):

$M<\infty$ because $B$ is almost surely continuous and thus bounded when restricted to a compact set

Comment: That's what I've said, but we only have $M<\infty$ **almost surely**.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Almost surely is the most you can possibly say about any property of $B_t$.

Comment: It is good practice to make edits to your question visible as such, especially when those edits are motivated by a response to your question. What you said in the question I answered to was that M was finite because of Riemann integrability of the Brownian motion, and you asked whether this argument was correct. And David is right, when you give me a Brownian motion, I can change it on a null set to be constant infinity and it will still be a Brownian motion

Comment: @Bananach But it's essentially the same argument. Since $K$ is compact and $B$ is continuous, $B$ is Riemann integrable and the Riemann integral and the Lebesgue integral coincide. I've edited the question cause I want to make clear that my real question is how I need to handle the null set.

Comment: It is essentially the same, indeed. But with your current edit it is the exact same. Therefore it would be nice to format your question in a way to reflect the change of focus. But no hard feelings, the null set question is clear now?

Comment: @Bananach You're right, the edit is a bit unlucky. I just didn't want to make things too confusing. Regarding the null set: I assume we need to modify $W$ on the null set such that it's well-defined. Probably that's all we can do.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is something like "Every $L^\infty$ function is bounded". By the mere definition of $L^\infty$ you won't be able to do so, because they are only defined up to sets of measure zero. Note that these measure zero sets corresponds to PROBABILISTIC measure zero sets in your question. You will never be able to prove something that holds for EVERY path of a Brownian motion, simply because a Brownian motion is only defined up to almost all its paths